# Structure sequence for a Curve on a Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a very basic question of Algebraic Geometry.

Let X be a smooth algebraic surface (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $C$ be a curve (smooth irreducible) on $X$. Can somebody very kindly explain me what is the meaning of the so called ''structure sequence''

$$ 0 \longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(-C)\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_C\longrightarrow 0 $$

Also, what is meant by ''tensoring this sequence with $\mathcal{O}_X(C)$'' ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not so clear what you're asking; the meaning is that there is an exact sequence of sheaves on $X$ of this form. Perhaps the issue is what the maps in the sequence are: the map $O_X \rightarrow O_C$ is restriction of a local regular function on $X$ to one on $C$. The kernel of this restriction is precisely the ideal sheaf $I_C$, and then the point is that (in the situation you describe) that is isomorphic to the invertible sheaf $O_X(-C)$.

Comment: For the second question, whenever one has a map of $R$-modules $f:A \rightarrow B$ and another such module $C$, one obtains a map $f \otimes \mathrm{id}:A \otimes C \rightarrow B \otimes C$ which sends $a \otimes c$ to $f(a) \otimes c$. This extends to sheaves. Note that tensoring by $O_X(C)$ (or indeed any locally free sheaf) is exact, so it turns your exact sequence into another exact sequence, namely $0 \rightarrow O_X \rightarrow O_X(C) \rightarrow O_C(C) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: If you're not familiar with $O_X$, $O_C$ and so on, best to look those up in a textbook. If you want to know why $I_C \cong O_X(-C)$, think about rational functions: local sections of $I_C$ are local regular functions which vanish along $C$, while local sections of $O_X(C)$ are local rational functions with at worst simple poles along $C$. Check that these are dual!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the exact sequence arising from the ideal sheaf of $C$ in $X$.

In other words: $C$ is a closed subscheme of $X$, so let us denote by $i:C\to X$ the closed immersion. When one writes $\mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_C$, one actually means $i^\sharp:\mathcal O_X\to i_\ast\mathcal O_C$, but the abuse of notation is justified in the sense that $i_\ast\mathcal O_C$ is zero outside of $C$. Now, this arrow is surjective by definition of closed immersion. This explains the right part of the sequence. The left part is just: take the kernel of this surjective map $\mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_C$. This kernel is by definition the ideal sheaf $\mathcal I_{C/X}$ of $C$ in $X$, and it coincides with $\mathcal O_X(-C)$ (in this case, $C$ is a divisor).

When you tensor an exact sequence, it just means that you apply a functor. In this case, the functor $$\mathcal O_X(C)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}-$$ applied to your short exact sequence gives a new exact sequence on $X$: $$0\to \mathcal O_X\to \mathcal O_X(C)\to \mathcal O_X(C)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal O_C\to 0.$$

(It stays exact since you tensor with a locally free sheaf)

Comment: Dear Brenin, thanks for your answer. Why is $\mathcal I_{C/X}=\mathcal O_X(-C)$ ?

Comment: For every open set $U$, $\mathcal{O}_X(-C)(U)=\{f\in \mathbb{C}(X):\mbox{div}(f)|_U-C|_U\geq0\}=\{f\in \mathbb{C}(X):f|_U\mbox{ is zero on }C\cap U\}$. This sheaf is the ideal sheaf of $C$, since the condition $\mbox{div}(f)|_U\geq C|_U$ also makes $f$ regular (on a sufficiently nice scheme such as $X$).